# How to solve this linear congruence equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to solve this linear congruence equation?

How to solve $6x \equiv 5 \mod 14$?

Answer (score 3):

It can't have a solution since $6$ and the modulus are even, and $5$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\ 6x\equiv 5\pmod{14}\iff 6x+14y\, =\, 5\ $ for some integer $\,y$.

Deduce a contradiction by comparing the *parity* of both sides of the prior equaton.

**Remark** $\ $ Generally $\ ax\equiv b\pmod n\iff ax\!+\!ny\,=\, b\,$ for some integer $\,b.\,$
So $\, \gcd(a,n)\,$ divides $\,ax\!+\!ny = b,\,$ i.e. $\ \gcd(a,n)\mid b\,$ is a *necessary* condition for solvability.   By Bezout's identity for the gcd this condition is also *sufficient* for solvability (hint: [scale the Bezout identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) for the gcd).